# parse .yml as an object (Kotlin)

Tags: parsing, kotlin, yaml, anchor, snakeyaml

I have a .yml

```
anchor: &my_anchor
  id: my_id
  name: my_name

ref: *my_anchor
```

Here are my classes in the code

```
class Response {
    latenit var anchor: MyAnchor
    lateinit var ref: MyAnchor
}

open class MyAnchor {

    lateinit var id: String
    lateinit var name: String
}
```

and here is a SnakeYaml code to parse a file

```
val result = Yaml(Constructor(Response::class.java)).loadAs(content, Response::class.java)
```

Everything seems to be ok except the fact that the property "ref" of the class "Response" has type "LinkedHashMap" but not "MyAnchor". I got a message like this

```
field ref has type MyAnchor, got java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

Maybe I should set some tags? I Will be grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem is that the class MyAnchor::class is an open one. Any model entity class should be final